# Why does simple email obfuscation work so well?

Tags: obfuscation, web-crawler, spam-prevention, email-spam

For example replacing `@` with `at`. At least one [study](http://www.ioc.ornl.gov/publications/ceas09.pdf) demonstrated its effectiveness:

> *To our surprise, none of the crawlers that visited our departmental research and course and research web pages led to any spam on email addresses containing the `at`.*

Another [experiment](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/) demonstrated the same thing, showing that using `at` and `dot` reduced spam by two orders of magnitude.

The first study speculated that spammers obtain enough plain-text email addresses to ignore the obfuscated ones. But parsing `at` in addition to `@` should be trivial. Why don't spammers account for such simple obfuscation?

Comment: @tylerthemiler and @gladoscc both offer the valid point that parsing `at` in addition to `@` is in fact _not_ trivial. It can result in a lot of false positives because `at` is such a common sequence of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert...but it intuitively makes sense that the @ symbol is much less commonly used in non-email-related speech. The @ sign is what set an email address apart from all the other text. If you simply use at, it blends in with normal English.

At is a pretty common word after all :P I'm sure its still possible to parse out the "at" version of an email, but just much more difficult of a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Why would they bother if they can find hundreds of thousands of plaintext ones? Additionally, what if a email had the word at or dot? like dottie@gmail.com - with a simple find and repalce would change it to .ie@gmail.com